# Como permitir a inserção de informação no banco usando DBLookupComboBox?

Tags: delphi, firebird, combobox

Tenho um `DBLookupComboBox` que captura os dados da tabela *Espécie* para que o usuário selecione o que precisa, após isso esses dados são salvos na tabela *Animal*.

Minha dúvida é como consigo fazer para permitir ao usuário adicionar um novo registro no `DBLookupComboBox` em tempo de execução e que esse seja salvo no banco de dados após o usuário confirmar que deseja fazer isso.

Comment: Vamos dizer que você tem um animal, e na hora de escolher o a especie no dblookcombobox não existe a relativa, então você quer que o usuário possa cadastrar uma nova especie, escolher-la e então cadastrar o animal?

Comment: @Artur_Indio, eu quero que ele digite no proprio combo e já cadastre.

Comment: Programaticamente tem muitas formas de fazer isso, usar os componentes DBLookupComboBox ou DBComboBox não vai dar pois não se pode editar neles. Você pode usar um Combobox e então carregar os item do dataset pra ele e então deixar o usuário editar e colocar um novo, quando clicar no botão salvar você faz uma forma de salvar tambem a tabela espécie, a forma que você salvar e gerar o id vai ser o id que vai para animal.

Comment: @Artur_Indio, eu teria que setar alguma propriedade para permitir ao usuario editar? Formula isso numa resposta que acredito que vai resolver meu problema :D

Comment: @Artur_Indio, eh como dito pelo Qmechanic73?

Comment: Eu acho que como dito por Qmechanic73 não da, pq você tem que salvar o ID da Especie antes, para então salvar o Animal usando o ID da Especie, a tabela Animal tem chave estrangeira pra Especie certo?

Comment: @Artur_Indio, concordo com você, tem que fazer desta maneira. Muito obrigado

Comment: Eu particularmente faço desta forma, uso o DBLookupComboBox para trazer os nomes das especies, caso não tenha a especie para quele animal eu coloco um botão vizinho ao DBLookupComboBox que abre uma janelinha para cadastrar a nova Especie, quando o user digitar o nome da especie e dar o ok, dou um refresh no dataset o qual o DBLookupComboBox tá ligado e coloco ele para o ultimo registro, no caso o que o usuario acabou de cadastrar.

Comment: Legal @Artur_Indio, uma ótima ideia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a sua ideia é fazer com que o usuário possa editar o conteúdo selecionado no `DBLookupComboBox`, isso pode não ser possível, pois o objetivo desse controle é listar os dados de uma tabela conforme especificado na propriedade `ListSource`.

Se é isso o que você quer fazer, talvez o `DBComboBox` possa servir melhor para esse caso.

O que você pode fazer para contornar isso é através do evento `onClick` de um botão.

```pascal
const
MSG1 = 'Digite uma nova espécie:';
MSG2 = 'Tem certeza que deseja gravar a espécie %s no banco?';
var
 Entrada: string;
begin
Entrada := InputBox(Caption, MSG1, '');
if Length(Entrada) = 0 then Exit;
if MessageDlg(Format(MSG2, [Entrada]), mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo then Exit;

Tabela1.Append;
Tabela1.FieldByName('Campo1').AsString := Entrada;
...
```

É necessário vincular a propriedade `ListSource` do `DBLookupComboBox` ao `DataSource` da tabela desejada.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta :D